# is there a way to broadcast tensor in tensordot operation in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to multiply stacked matrix which is expressed in tensor form.

```
tensor.shape == [2,5,7,6]
```

where 2 and 5 is size of batch,

`tensor2.shape == [5,6,8]`

where 5 is batch size.

In numpy, tensor2 is automatically broadcasted to [2,5,7,6] tensor

so I can easily use `np.matmul(tensor,tensor2)`

but in tensorflow, error occurs.

I tried `tf.expand_dims(tensor2,0)` but this also doesn't work

is there any way to broadcast tensor in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tf.einsum`:

```
tf.einsum('abij,bjk->abik', tensor, tensor2)
```

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.zeros((2, 5, 7, 6))
y = tf.zeros((5, 6, 8))
z = tf.einsum('abij,bjk->abik', x, y)
z.shape.as_list()
# returns [2, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I tried this, but this result in tensor shape of 2,7,8 is there did I miss?

Comment: I don't know -- I added a small example for you to check.

Answer (score 1):

The most general and appropriate way to tackle such problems is to use [tf.einsum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum). This function allows you to directly specify the multiplication rules using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) which was invented to operate with tensors of arbitrary dimenstions.